# How can I get checkbox attribute with using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I' m using MVC and set an itemId attribute to checkboxes.

```
@Html.CheckBox("check", false, new { itemId = item.ID  })
```

Now I want to get this attribute with ***using javascipt*** but I could not.

I got the checkboxes list with this code:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check');
```

Are there any solution for it?

Comment: don't want to use jquery???

Comment: Yes, I don't. Do I have to use jquery to solve it?

Comment: you can use element.getAttribute(attributename) to get the value of an attribute without jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help:

```
var itemId = document.getElementsByName('check')[0].getAttribute('itemId');
```